# Как поменять цвет фигуры в TKinter?

Tags: python, tkinter

```
from tkinter import *
gl = Tk()
con = Canvas(gl, width=500, height=500, bg="white")
con.pack()
con.create_oval(110, 90, 130, 70, fill = 'blue', outline = 'blue')
gl.mainloop()
```

Есть небольшой участок кода на Python. Помогите пожалуйста сделать так что, сначала появляется овал с начальным цветом а потом, через секунд 5, он меняет на другой цвет. Заранее спасибо.

Comment: Не нужно удалять вопрос после того как вам дали ответ. Ответы не только для вас, но и для будущих посетителей сайта. Если вы считаете, что ответ вам помог, вы можете отметить его галкой слева от ответа (см. [Что делать с ответами на мой вопрос?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers))

Answer (score 1):

Для планирования выполнения действия через какой-то промежуток времени нужно использовать метод `after` объекта `Tk`. Он принимает длительность задержки в миллисекундах и функцию, которую нужно выполнить.

Для изменения параметров объекта на холсте - метод `itemconfig`. Он принимает id объекта (число, которое возвращает метод создания объекта, в данном случае - `create_oval`) и изменяемые параметры.

```
from tkinter import *

gl = Tk()
con = Canvas(gl, width=500, height=500, bg="white")
con.pack()
oval_id = con.create_oval(110, 90, 130, 70, fill = 'blue', outline = 'blue')

def change_color():
    # Поменять цвет овала:
    con.itemconfig(oval_id, fill='yellow', outline='yellow')

# Выполнить change_color через 5 секунд
gl.after(5000, change_color)

gl.mainloop()
```